# ¿Cómo puedo centrar este elemento con CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Tengo un elemento que no puedo centrar, he probado con `align text center`, `justify content center`, `align item center` y siempre se termina yendo a la izquierda, quisiera saber porque ocurre esto y como solucionarlo.

Este es el código:

```css
.caja {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6rem;
  background-color: #8b2626;
  max-width: 70rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main class="caja">
  <div id="info">
    <p>NOMBREA</p>
    <p>RAZA</p>
    <p>NOMBREB</p>
  </div>
  <div id="info2">
    <h2>HORA</h2>
    <h1>NOMBREC</h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: primero que nada en `.caja` agrega `display: flex;`, luego si queres centrar los `divs` que se encuentran adentro también utiliza `flexbox`

Comment: Agregué un snippet para tener una vista previa de tu código y hasta donde veo, parece centrado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que la caja pueda quedar correctamente centrada, debes definir un margen automático, ya que si lo defines de manera manual, no coinciden los márgenes para que se ajuste automáticamente en el centro.
con tan solo reemplazar **margin: 70rem;** por **margin: auto;** tu problema queda resuelto.

```
.caja{
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #8b2626;
  max-width: 70rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo eres el mejor!